# why i cannot display data get from database in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, hsqldb

i want to display all order get from my database. my OrderDate is set type as Date and the other i set as String. but i get an error "Unknown property OrderDate".  below is my JSP code use to display data.

```
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@page import="booking.Bean.Order"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Vector"%>
<%@page import="booking.Wrapper.Wrapper"%>
<%@page import="booking.DB.OrderDB"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link href="css/displaytag.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/alternative.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>All Order Details</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <jsp:include page="header.jsp" />
        </div>

        <div id="menu">
        <ul>

                <li class="menuitem"><a href="aboutC.jsp">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="clientsC.jsp">Menu</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="contactC.jsp">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="login.jsp">Logout</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div id="leftmenu">

            <div id="leftmenu_top"></div>

            <div id="leftmenu_main">

                <jsp:include page="orderMenu.jsp" />
            </div>


            <div id="leftmenu_bottom"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <div id="content_top"></div>
            <div id="content_main">
            <h2>All Order Details</h2>
                <%

                OrderDB orderDB = new OrderDB();
                Wrapper myWrapper = new Wrapper();
                Vector<Order> viewAllOrders = myWrapper.viewAllOrders();

                //SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

                if (viewAllOrders.size() !=0)
                {
                    request.setAttribute("disOrder", viewAllOrders);
                    %>          
                <display:table name="disOrder" export="true" pagesize="10" class="Mars"  >
                    <display:column sortable="true" property="orderId" title="Order ID" />
                    <display:column sortable="true" property="custId" title="Customer ID" />
                    <display:column sortable="true" property="OrderDate" format="{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd}" title="Order Date" />
                    <display:column sortable="true" property="OrderTime" title="Order Time" />
                    <display:column sortable="true" property="OrderSeat" title="Order Seat" />
                    <display:column sortable="true" property="BStatus" title="Order Status" />
                    <display:column sortable="true" property="OCustName" title="Customer Name" />       
                    <display:column sortable="true" property="cOEmail" title="Email" />
                    <display:column sortable="true" property="cOPhoneNo" title="Contact No"/>
                    <display:column sortable="true" property="defaulter" title="Defaulter" />
                </display:table>
                <%
                }
                else
                {
                    out.print("<h4>No data found!</h4>");
                }
                %>


            </div>
            <div id="content_bottom"></div>

            <jsp:include page="footer.jsp"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

below is the exception get by the system.

```
Nov 21, 2012 9:22:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Table_Booking] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception: [.LookupUtil] Error looking up property "OrderDate" in object type "booking.Bean.Order". Cause: Unknown property 'OrderDate'] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'OrderDate'
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1122)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtils.java:408)
    at org.displaytag.util.LookupUtil.getProperty(LookupUtil.java:271)
    at org.displaytag.util.LookupUtil.getBeanProperty(LookupUtil.java:129)
    at org.displaytag.model.Column.getValue(Column.java:124)
    at org.displaytag.model.Column.createChoppedAndLinkedValue(Column.java:201)
    at org.displaytag.model.Column.initialize(Column.java:178)
    at org.displaytag.render.TableWriterTemplate.writeTableBody(TableWriterTemplate.java:313)
    at org.displaytag.render.TableWriterTemplate.writeTable(TableWriterTemplate.java:138)
    at org.displaytag.render.HtmlTableWriter.writeTable(HtmlTableWriter.java:734)
    at org.displaytag.tags.TableTag.writeHTMLData(TableTag.java:1647)
    at org.displaytag.tags.TableTag.doEndTag(TableTag.java:1300)
    at org.apache.jsp.displayOrder_jsp._jspx_meth_display_005ftable_005f0(displayOrder_jsp.java:262)
    at org.apache.jsp.displayOrder_jsp._jspService(displayOrder_jsp.java:151)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Nov 21, 2012 9:22:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Table_Booking] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception: [.LookupUtil] Error looking up property "OrderDate" in object type "booking.Bean.Order". Cause: Unknown property 'OrderDate'] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'OrderDate'
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1122)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtils.java:408)
    at org.displaytag.util.LookupUtil.getProperty(LookupUtil.java:271)
    at org.displaytag.util.LookupUtil.getBeanProperty(LookupUtil.java:129)
    at org.displaytag.model.Column.getValue(Column.java:124)
    at org.displaytag.model.Column.createChoppedAndLinkedValue(Column.java:201)
    at org.displaytag.model.Column.initialize(Column.java:178)
    at org.displaytag.render.TableWriterTemplate.writeTableBody(TableWriterTemplate.java:313)
    at org.displaytag.render.TableWriterTemplate.writeTable(TableWriterTemplate.java:138)
    at org.displaytag.render.HtmlTableWriter.writeTable(HtmlTableWriter.java:734)
    at org.displaytag.tags.TableTag.writeHTMLData(TableTag.java:1647)
    at org.displaytag.tags.TableTag.doEndTag(TableTag.java:1300)
    at org.apache.jsp.displayOrder_jsp._jspx_meth_display_005ftable_005f0(displayOrder_jsp.java:262)
    at org.apache.jsp.displayOrder_jsp._jspService(displayOrder_jsp.java:151)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

can anyone help me solve this problem??? thank you for your help.

Comment: do you have `OrderDate` defined in your bean class `Order` ?

Comment: i already defined OrderDate in my bean class and set it as Date format.

Comment: have you tried what @bobah answered

Comment: already try but still get same error.

Comment: Does your OrderDate field have a public getter called `getOrderDate()`?

Answer (score 2):

Change uppercase to lowercase: **O** rderDate -> **o** rderDate, same with some other fields

Comment: all of the related variable i change to lowercase already but it still get the same error.

Comment: make sure your Order class has getOrderDate() getter method

Comment: try bisection, remove OrderDate and see if OrderTime crashes (it does not have format specified), if still crashes remove half of fields and continue till you have a set of fields that displays fine, next - compare those working with those not working. This all is in assumption that the code your jsp sees is exactly the code you are looking at in the editor (no stale deployed classes).